# Orientation of a 3D triangle vertices

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, triangles, 3d, orthonormal

I have a 3D triangle which represent a plane. How to determine whether the vertices are oriented clockwise or anti clockwise. I need this because I'm calculating normal for triangle which resides on a plane and depending on the orientation the direction of the normal of the plane changes. Like if the triangle resides on a plane where z = 0, then the normal could be (0,0,1) or (0,0,-1).

Comment: Downvoting because your question makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: I have modified the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Counterclockwise in $\mathbb{R}^3$ already presumes a choice of normal direction.

The reason counterclockwise is determined for the $xy$-plane is because, regarding it as the plane $z=0\;$in $\mathbb{R}^3$, we implicitly assume an upwards directed normal vector (i.e., we view the plane from above).

So if you choose a normal vector for your plane, you can define counterclockwise as "counterclockwise from above", where "above" is based on the chosen normal direction.

In a given context, there may be a natural choice of normal direction, but otherwise, there are two possible directions, and the choice is arbitrary.

Comment: I have a 3D cube which defines 6 planes with its 6 faces and the cube is aligned with XYZ axises. Inside that cube I have some arbitrary triangles. I'm trying to project each of these triangles to one of the planes by calculating the angle between the triangle and each of the 6 cube faces. The cube face for which I get minimum angle I project the triangle on that face. I can't get my head around on how to calculate the normal consistently. Because for a triangle having vertices v1, v2, v3 it may project onto one face but changing the order of the vertices it would project on the opposite face.

Comment: But it won't be same for all of the opposing faces. Suppose a triangle has z=0. So its lying on xy plane which is the front of the cube face. So for this case if the front cube face has normal (0,0,1) then the back will have (0,0,-1) and if the triangle normal is (0,0,1) then its 0 degree angle between front face but 180 degree for the opposite face. But it will have same angle(90 degree) with all the other faces.

Comment: But the angle between normal of the two planes can't be always between [0,π/2]. If the front face of the cube normal (0,0,1) and the back face cube normal (0,0,-1) then the angle between them is 180.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66475/discussion-between-tahlil-and-quasi).